# MySQL optimize table

Tags: mysql, optimization

I have a table which record the bandwidth usage in MySQL. Every minute I have a new record. Here is my table :

```
+------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field            | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| IfInOctets       | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| IfOutOctets      | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| inDiff           | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| outDiff          | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| time             | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| timeDiff         | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| inDiffFormatted  | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| outDiffFormatted | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

I think I need to use integer instead of varchar but I'm not sure about that.

Here is a sample data :

```
+------------+-------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+--------------------+--------------------+
| IfInOctets | IfOutOctets | inDiff     | outDiff    | time       | timeDiff   | inDiffFormatted    | outDiffFormatted   |
+------------+-------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+--------------------+--------------------+
| 2147483647 | 1376607409  | 2460390830 | 1376607409 | 1556176316 | 1556176316 | 1.2062445720411E-5 | 6.7490302544245E-6 |
| 2147483647 | 1376607409  | 0          | 0          | 1556176321 | 5          | 0                  | 0                  |
| 2147483647 | 1376828650  | 30146      | 221241     | 1556176381 | 60         | 0.003833262125651  | 0.028132247924805  |
| 2147483647 | 1377086102  | 27318      | 257452     | 1556176442 | 61         | 0.003416718029585  | 0.032200047227203  |
| 2147483647 | 1377214273  | 26182      | 128171     | 1556176501 | 59         | 0.003385640807071  | 0.016574019092624  |
| 2147483647 | 1377750582  | 17235      | 536309     | 1556176561 | 60         | 0.0021915435791016 | 0.068195215861003  |
| 2147483647 | 1378643334  | 56369      | 892752     | 1556176621 | 60         | 0.0071676890055339 | 0.11351928710938   |
| 2147483647 | 1384687953  | 168712     | 6044619    | 1556176681 | 60         | 0.021452840169271  | 0.76861305236816   |
| 2147483647 | 1385607549  | 132968     | 919596     | 1556176742 | 61         | 0.016630579213627  | 0.11501574907147   |
| 2147483647 | 1386144703  | 86602      | 537154     | 1556176801 | 59         | 0.011198658054158  | 0.069460335424391  |
| 2147483647 | 1386706605  | 36223      | 561902     | 1556176861 | 60         | 0.0046059926350911 | 0.071449534098307  |
| 2147483647 | 1387068552  | 78973      | 361947     | 1556176921 | 60         | 0.010041936238607  | 0.046023941040039  |
| 2147483647 | 1388695622  | 127944     | 1627070    | 1556176981 | 60         | 0.016268920898438  | 0.20689264933268   |
| 2147483647 | 1389068366  | 140436     | 372744     | 1556177041 | 60         | 0.017857360839844  | 0.047396850585937  |
| 2147483647 | 1389279305  | 68037      | 210939     | 1556177101 | 60         | 0.0086513519287109 | 0.026822280883789  |
| 2147483647 | 1389417338  | 46582      | 138033     | 1556177162 | 61         | 0.0058261058369621 | 0.017264069103804  |
| 2147483647 | 1389589892  | 37450      | 172554     | 1556177221 | 59         | 0.004842725850768  | 0.0223132634567    |
| 2147483647 | 1390475078  | 62933      | 885186     | 1556177281 | 60         | 0.0080023447672526 | 0.11255722045898   |
| 2147483647 | 1391155868  | 83365      | 680790     | 1556177341 | 60         | 0.010600407918294  | 0.086566925048828  |
| 2147483647 | 1392049156  | 68532      | 893288     | 1556177401 | 60         | 0.0087142944335938 | 0.11358744303385   |
| 2147483647 | 1392862166  | 108235     | 813010     | 1556177462 | 61         | 0.013537172411309  | 0.10168482045658   |
| 2147483647 | 1392960189  | 10691      | 98023      | 1556177521 | 59         | 0.0013824721514168 | 0.012675527798927  |
| 2147483647 | 1393207096  | 18882      | 246907     | 1556177581 | 60         | 0.0024009704589844 | 0.031395848592122  |
| 2147483647 | 1393448878  | 13595      | 241782     | 1556177641 | 60         | 0.0017286936442057 | 0.030744171142578  |
| 2147483647 | 1408075956  | 288098     | 14627078   | 1556177701 | 60         | 0.036633555094401  | 1.8599291483561    |
| 2147483647 | 1427800637  | 344325     | 19724681   | 1556177762 | 61         | 0.043065430688076  | 2.4670061205254    |
| 2147483647 | 1449947549  | 315400926  | 22146912   | 1556177821 | 59         | 40.785052541959    | 2.8638564287606    |
| 2147483647 | 1470058156  | 315793135  | 20110607   | 1556177882 | 61         | 39.496892084841    | 2.5152746732118    |
| 2147483647 | 1489563366  | 316133487  | 19505210   | 1556177941 | 59         | 40.879781302759    | 2.5222532627946    |
| 2147483647 | 1511595700  | 316511799  | 22032334   | 1556178002 | 61         | 39.58677685847     | 2.7556289922996    |
+------------+-------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+--------------------+--------------------+
```

Comment: All fields must be of numeric types. FLOAT or DOUBLE for last 2 fields, and INT or BIGINT (dependent by theoretical maximal value) for all another. If last 2 fields can be calculated from all another field's values, they must be removed at all.

Comment: I don't really understand why I should delete the last column. I don't really know the max value it can get

Comment: When some field value can be calculated from another field's values, it must be removed, and its value must be calculated in the query where it needed. Exclusions are too rare, and only in very special cases.

Comment: The query would take more time to calculate ?

Comment: Yes. But the time difference is less than time compare accuracy.

Comment: @Akina If I use `bigint(20)` for `IfInOctets` what is the maximum value I can store ?

Comment: [MySQL 8.0 Reference Manual  /  Integer Types (Exact Value) - INTEGER, INT, SMALLINT, TINYINT, MEDIUMINT, BIGINT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/integer-types.html)

Comment: Consider using `UNSIGNED` to double the maximum positive value

Comment: How can I use `UNSIGNED` ? I changed the type like `BIGINT` only. Should I add an id column even if I don't need it ?